# Wordpress load more comments

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I am making a page that has to show 4 wordpress comments, and then there is a way to load more comments by clicking on a button.
Is there a way to show more wordpress comments with a button?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but still has no answer.

Implementing load more button for comments is much simpler than for posts, you just need to

1. Create a button if comment pages are 2 and more
2. Create a jQuery script that will process the button click event and passes the current comment page number to `wp_ajax_` action hook
3. The last step – `wp_ajax_` function that will process the AJAX request.

That's all!

But if you need the ready code, please look at this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-comments.html

Answer (score -1):

The ajax comment loading plugin can be useful for this too. That one will load comments according to Google specification so it is good for when the google bot crawls your comments.

**https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/**

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for comments, only for pages and posts.

Comment: It does work with an add-on, https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/add-ons/comments/